# Python/ Django form- how to 'save' value entered in a form 'DateInput' field?

Tags: python, django, forms, widget

I have a form displayed on one of my Django project webpages- the first field in the form accepts an integer in a text input field, the second displays another integer in a text input field, and the third displays a date value.

Currently, when the user first loads this page, the integers displayed in fields one and two are already populated (the first has been retrieved from the database, and the value of the second is calculated based on the value of the first). The date field is blank.

However, if I change the value of the first integer field, and refresh the page, the new values for fields one and two are automatically loaded (i.e. the `view` used to display this webpage registers the changes to the value, and updates the database, so that when it retrieves the values when the page is reloaded, the new values are what it finds.

But, for some reason, when I select a date in the third field, and refresh the page, the date field is always blank when the page is reloaded... It seems that either the date is not being saved when a value is entered, or it is not loaded when the page loads.

The view being used to display this page in the browser is:

```
def concept(request, project_id):
    ...
    deposit = Deposit.objects.get_or_create(project=project)[0]
    ...

    context = {
        ...
        'deposit_form': DepositInfoForm(instance=deposit),
        ...
    }

    return render(request, 'projects/concept.html', context)
```

The `DepositInfoForm` on which the 'date' field that I'm having the rouble with is defined in `forms.py`:

```
class DepositInfoForm(ValidatedForm):
    amount_exc_vat = forms.IntegerField(required=False, widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'currency',}),label="Deposit exc VAT")
    amount_inc_vat = forms.IntegerField(required=False, widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'currency', 'readonly':'readonly',}),label="Inc VAT")
    date_received = mDateField(required=False, label="Date deposit received", widget=forms.DateInput(format='%d/%m/%Y', attrs=({'class':'datepicker'})))

    class Meta:
        model = Deposit
        fields = ('amount_exc_vat', 'amount_inc_vat', 'date_received')#,'received')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = kwargs.get('instance', {})
        project = instance.project

        try: amount_exc_vat = int(round(instance.amount_exc_vat))
        except TypeError: amount_exc_vat = None
        try: amount_inc_vat = int(round(project.deposit.amount_inc_vat))
        except TypeError: amount_inc_vat = None
        # ERF(21/11/2016 @ 11:00) Add a 'try' for date_deposit_received
        #try: date_deposit_received = project.date_deposit_received
        #except TypeError: date_deposit_received = None

        initial = kwargs.get('initial', {})
        initial={
                'received': project.deposit_received,
                'amount_exc_vat': amount_exc_vat,
                'amount_inc_vat': amount_inc_vat,
                }
        kwargs['initial'] = initial

        super(DepositInfoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['date_received'].widget.attrs.update({'data-original-value': self.initial['date_received'] or ''})

    def save(self, commit=True):
        deposit = self.instance
        data = self.cleaned_data

        if 'date_received' in self.changed_data:
            if not data['date_received'] == '':
                deposit.project.deposit_received = True;
                self.deposit_r = True
                deposit.project.upgrade_detailed_status(Project.ds75)
            else:
                deposit.project.deposit_received = False;       
            deposit.project.save()

        if ('amount_exc_vat' in self.changed_data or 'date_received' in self.changed_data or 'received' in self.changed_data) and data['amount_exc_vat'] and data['date_received'] and data['received']:
            send_message(message_template=2, project=self.instance.project)
            self.deposit_r = True       

        if hasattr(self, 'deposit_r'):
            # Make the payment
            deposit_payment = Payment(project=deposit.project, is_booking_deposit=True, amount_exc_vat=data['amount_exc_vat'], date_paid=data['date_received'])

        return super(DepositInfoForm, self).save(commit=commit)
```

I tried adding `deposit_received` to the `def __init__(...)` method, but got an

> AttributeError
>
> > 'Project' object has no attribute 'deposit_received'

I think that the issue with the date not being displayed when loading the page is to do with the `__init__(...)` function, but can't seem to work out what the issue is.. anyone have any ideas how I can get this field to be automatically populated with the date that was saved?

**Edit**

I resolved the `AttributeError` by changing the `try` that I had added to:

```
try: date_received = project.deposit.date_received
except TypeError: date_received = None
```

However, although the page now loads and displays again properly, after reloading, the 'date' field remains empty, rather than being populated by the value that the user entered before reloading the page...

So, it would seem that it's the `save` method in the above code that isn't working correctly for the `date_received` field- even though there's a call to `save()` in that block:

```
if 'date_received' in self.changed_data:
    if not data['date_received'] == '':
        deposit.project.deposit_received = True;
        self.deposit_r = True
        deposit.project.upgrade_detailed_status(Project.ds75)
    else:
        deposit.project.deposit_received = False;       
    deposit.project.save()
```

Comment: Well, the field is called `date_received`, not `depost_received`. If you want any more help you should show the modified code and the full traceback.

Comment: I resolved the `AttributeError`, but for some reason the date is still not displayed when refreshing the page... any thoughts?